# JavaFX - Can't style Scroll Bar Increment/Decrement Button outside border via CSS properly

Tags: css, javafx, scrollbar

I simply cannot style the outside border of a scrollbar increment button.

Here is my code with a picture:

```
.scroll-bar:vertical .increment-button,
.scroll-bar:vertical .decrement-button {
    -fx-background-color: #000000;
    -fx-border-color: #38FB00;
    -fx-border-insets: 10, 10, 10, 10;
}
```

[image]

On picture above, the outside rim on the increment button stays default color, I would like to be able to paint that green as well.

How do I do that?

Comment: can you provide the full css of the your scroll pane / scroll bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comment, you need to provide the full CSS of your scroll bar.

With the below code, this is how the scroll bar looks. I don't see any grey border around the increment/decrement buttons.

[image]

```
.scroll-bar:vertical .increment-button,
.scroll-bar:vertical .decrement-button {
    -fx-background-color: #000000;
    -fx-border-color: #38FB00;
    -fx-border-insets: 10, 10, 10, 10;
}
.scroll-bar:vertical > .thumb {
    -fx-background-color: #38FB00;
}

.scroll-bar:vertical {
    -fx-background-color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Seems like it was this part missing, thanks for solution I googled it for days :)

.scroll-bar:vertical {
    -fx-background-color: #000000;
}